# Android Layout qualifiers don't work?

Tags: android, google-tv, qualifiers

I am developing an android using the API Google Tv Addon, i wanna use the screen qualifiers no touch, i created a folder under /res/  called layout-notouch, i named my layout test.xml,  in my activity when i put `setContentView(R.layout.test)` the application crash. how could i use this screen qualifier. Or otherwise, could i set qualifiers programatically. you can take a look here [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use layout-large-notouch for layout and drawable-land-xhdpi for drawables to target Google TV.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the layout-notouch is not working.You can find the google bug report at this links https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20087

Some people  are suggesting to use  resource qualifiers  layout-tvdpi-notouch (720) & layout-xhdpi-notouch (1080),layout-large-notouch.

But not sure the suggestion is working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about what I'm about to say, but it seems to me that "notouch" qualifiers will not work because current Google-TVs support some sort of touch. You have a trackpad that acts as a mouse and you can click on things, simulating "touch" events.

If in the GTV emulator you edit the avd settings, you can specifically declare the "touch screen type" as "notouch". Then, if you run your application under those conditions you will see that the "notouch" qualifiers work. This means that by default "touch-screen type" is set to "touch" instead of "notouch".